# How to render django html templates as plain text?

Tags: django, email, template-engine

Is there any mechanism in django to render html as plain text. For example render the following:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
```

As:

Title

Paragraph

Specially for attaching text alternative for HTML emails

Edit: I am not asking about HTML string. What I actually mean is plain text with out tags. Only considering things such as new lines. Similar to lynx browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For mailing:**

Django includes the `django.core.mail.send_mail` method

```py
    from django.core import mail
    from django.template.loader import render_to_string
    from django.utils.html import strip_tags

    subject = 'Subject'
    # mail_template.html is in your template dir and context key you can pass to 
    # your template dynamically
    html_message = render_to_string('mail_template.html', {'context': 'values'})
    plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)
    from_email = 'From <from@example.com>'
    to = 'to@example.com'

    mail.send_mail(subject, plain_message, from_email, [to], html_message=html_message)
```

This will send an email which is visible in both html-capable browsers and will show plain text in crippled email viewers.

**To send normal html as string:**

You can return an `HttpResponse` and pass string which contain valid HTML in it

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse

def Index(request):
    text = """
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    """
    # above variable will be rendered as a valid html
    return HttpResponse(text)
```

But good practice is always return a template and keep your templates in other directories doesn't matter if you want to render only one tag. YOur can use `render` method for that:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

*Note: make sure you specify your templates folder in `TEMPLATES` variable in `settings.py` so that django will know form where it should render the templates*

Comment: "strip_tags" is what I was looking for Thanks a lot Shubham.

Answer (score 0):

You can use render_to_string to convert template to string.

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
render_to_string('path_to_template',context={'key','value'})
```